# Split ArrayList of integers using RxJava

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, split, rx-java

I am trying to split an list of integers into smaller arrays (ranges) by values from another list. So, for instance, having an array with such values

```
[100, 10, 4000, 9, 3000, 1024, 15, 660, 999]
```

And array of values to split by.

```
[20, 300, 500, 1000, 10000]
```

I want to get arrays with values, that are less then corresponding values. Like

```
20 -- [9, 10, 15] // (value from first array < 20)
300 -- [100]  // (20 <= value < 300)
500 -- [] // (300 <= value < 500)
1000 -- [660, 999] // (500 <= value < 1000)
10000 -- [1024, 3000, 4000] // (1000 <= value < 10000)
```

Is there any way to implement this using RxJava? Or any fast algorithm to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have some ideas how to implement this in not too optimal way just iterating over values array and than comparing it to each element in ranges array. But this seems to be not too optimal.

Comment: Maybe the best way is to compare sorted list of values with also sorted array of ranges, but I have no idea how to do this using RxJava

Comment: I'm working on code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using java8 streams,

```
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(100, 10, 4000, 9, 3000, 1024, 15, 660, 999);
    List<Integer> range = Arrays.asList(20, 300, 500, 1000, 10000); // sorted
    Function<Integer, Integer> between = n -> {
        for (Integer in : range) {
            if (in >= n)
                return in;
        }
        return -1;
    };
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> grouped = numbers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(between));
    System.out.println(grouped);
```

output

```
{10000=[4000, 3000, 1024], 20=[10, 9, 15], 1000=[660, 999], 300=[100]}
```

you can provide supplier as `TreeMap` in `groupingBy` to get the result in sorted.

**UPDATE**

To sort by key

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> grouped = numbers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(between, TreeMap::new, Collectors.mapping(k -> k, Collectors.toList())));
```

output

```
{20=[10, 9, 15], 300=[100], 1000=[660, 999], 10000=[4000, 3000, 1024]}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(100);
        list.add(10);
        list.add(4000);
        list.add(9);
        list.add(3000);
        list.add(1024);
        list.add(15);
        list.add(660);
        list.add(999);
        int[] splitValues = new int[]{20,300,500,1000,10000};
        int prev = 0;
        //100, 10, 4000, 9, 3000, 1024, 15, 660, 999
        Collections.sort(list);
        Map<Integer, Integer[]> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < splitValues.length; i++) {
            for (int j=prev;j<list.size();j++) {
                if(splitValues[i]<list.get(j)){
                    addRecord(map,list,j, splitValues[i],prev);
                    prev = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    private static void addRecord(Map<Integer, Integer[]> map, List<Integer> list, int j, int index, int start) {
        try {
            list = list.subList(start, j);          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("boo");
        }

        Integer[] arr = new Integer[j-start];
        list.toArray(arr);
        map.put(index, arr);

    }
```

The only problem is displaying it